# Die Verben zu Sinn und Unsinn

Tags: verb-usage, verb-choice

Warum heißt es:

> Es **macht** Sinn

aber

> Das **ist** Unsinn

?

Answer (score 8):

Deine Frage scheint davon auszugehen, dass *Unsinn* das Gegenteil von *Sinn* wäre - Das ist aber (wie bei sehr vielen "Un-"-Nomen, weniger bei den "un-"-Adjektiven) nicht der Fall (Dazu gibt es massenhaft Beispiele, z.B. *Untiefe*, was entweder eine sehr tiefe (sic) oder sehr flache Gewässerstelle bezeichnen kann. Zu vielen "Un-"-Nomen existiert auch das "Un-"-lose Nomen nicht oder nicht mehr - z.B. *Ungeheuer*).

*Unsinn* ist im modernen Sprachgebrauch nicht unbedingt die Abwesenheit von *Sinn* (was an sich naheligen würde), sondern eher die Abwesenheit von *Ernsthaftigkeit* oder *Vernunft*. (Genausowenig, wie im Englischen *sense* das Gegenteil von *nonsense* wäre)

*Unsinn* und *Sinn* haben also keine diametralen Bedeutungen, und da das nicht der Fall ist, kann man auch nicht davon ausgehen, dass sie mit den gleichen Verben verwendet werden.

<sup>(aus der Frage, ob "etwas macht Sinn" überhaupt korrektes Deutsch oder ein lieber nicht zu verwendender eingebürgerter Anglizismus ist, halte ich mich hier komplett raus - Sie wurde nicht gestellt)</sup>

Comment: Hm, _Unsinn_ ist meiner Ansicht nach nicht notwendigerweise das Gegenteil von _Sinn_, es gibt aber durchaus Bedeutungen der beiden Wörter, bei denen das zutrifft.

Comment: Es gibt auch durchaus Bedeutungen der beiden Wörter, bei denen man z.B. "macht Unsinn" sagen kann - Der Clown, z.B.

Comment: Ja, das stimmt.

Answer (score 4):

*Sinn* war bis vor wenigen Jahren in der Semantik der deutschen Sprache nichts, das man hätte herstellen oder erzeugen können. Der Satz

> Das macht Sinn.

galt daher bis vor relativ kurzer Zeit als genau falsch wie

> falsch: Das macht Unsinn.

Als richtig galten nur:

> richtig: Das ist sinnvoll. Das ist sinnlos. Das ist unsinnig.

Aber auch

> richtig: Ludwig macht Unsinn.

jedoch falsch:

> falsch: Ludwig macht Sinn.<sup>1</sup>

Das Substantiv *»Sinn«* wurde nur in diesen Kontexten verwendet:

> Der Sinn (Zweck) dieser Aktion ist, ...
> Ich hatte etwas anderes im Sinn. = Ich hatte mir etwas anderes vorgestellt.
> Judith hat Sinn für Humor. = Judith versteht Spaß. Judith hat eine Begabung für Humor.
> Seine Worte ergaben für mich einfach keinen Sinn. = Seine Worte waren für mich unverständlich.

und das sind Beispiele für *Unsinn:*

> Er redet nur Unsinn (wirres Zeug) daher.
> Manfred glaubt wirklich jeden Unsinn (Quatsch).
> Mach keinen Unsinn während ich weg bin. = Stelle nichts an während ich weg bin.

An diesen Beispielen kann man übrigens auch recht gut erkennen, dass Sinn und Unsinn auch in der Vergangenheit keine Wörter waren, die man auf dieselbe Weise verwendet hat.

---

Nun gibt es im Englischen seit jeher schon die Floskel

> It makes sense.

Die korrekte Übersetzung wäre

> Das ist sinnvoll.

Aber als der Gebrauch der englischen Sprache im deutschsprachigen Raum immer populärer wurde, begannen zuerst einige wenige den englischen grammatischen Bauplan des Satzes unreflektiert zu übernehmen und mit deutschen Vokabeln zu füllen. Heraus kam:

> Das macht Sinn.

Vor allem Germanisten im Rentenalter wird auch heute noch schlecht wenn sie das lesen. Aber die Mehrheit der Muttersprachler geht damit pragmatischer um: Wenn viele andere diese Konstruktion verwenden, kann sie nicht ganz falsch sein, also mache ich das auch so. - Und schon hat diese Konstruktion einen Anwender mehr.

Das sind genau die Mechanismen, die in lebenden Sprachen zu Veränderungen führen: Was früher als falsch galt, stößt nach wenigen Jahrzehnten nur noch bei einer konservativen Minderheit auf Ablehnung.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Wenn man die Konstruktion *»etwas macht Sinn«* akzeptiert, dann könnte man dem Satz *»Ludwig macht Sinn«* die folgende Bedeutung zuordnen: *Es ist sinnvoll, dass Ludwig existiert.*</sub>

Comment: Ich sehe hier vor allem eine Antwort auf die Frage, wie _etw. macht Sinn_ entstanden ist. Diese Antwort stützt sich im Wesentlichen auf vage Spekulationen: "Aber als der Gebrauch der englischen Sprache im deutschsprachigen Raum immer populärer wurde" - Wann war das genau?; "begannen zuerst einige wenige" - Wann genau? Wer genau? Oder: Wie viele genau?; "Vor allem Germanisten im Rentenalter" - hast du dafür einen Beleg? Ansonsten ist das eine sehr pauschale (und ich fürchte überdies: falsche) Aussage. Und schließlich scheint mir auch die eigentlich gestellte Frage kaum berührt.

Comment: Dein erster Satz:. „Sinn machen“ hat mit Grammatik nichts zu tun - das ist reine Semantik. Aus der Sicht der Grammatik sind solche Sätze absolut OK.

Comment: @tofro: Stimmt. Da muss ich dir zu 100% recht geben. Ich habe den Satz jetzt anders formuliert. (Eigentlich hätte ich es ja besser wissen müssen. Ich unterrichte Theoretische Informatik, wo es auch viel um Sprachen geht, jedoch aus einem sehr mathematischen Blickwinkel, und da ist unter den allerersten Kapiteln meiner Vorlesung ein kurzes Kapitel Semiotik dabei (Synatax (Grammatik) = Beziehung der Zeichen zueinander - Semantik (Bedeutung) = Beziehung der Zeichen zum Objekt  - Pragmatik (Interpretation) = Beziehung des Senders und Empfängers der Nachricht zu den Zeichen))

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach: *"Aber als der Gebrauch der englischen Sprache im deutschsprachigen Raum immer populärer wurde" - Wann war das genau?* --- Das begann nach dem zweiten Weltkrieg, getrieben unter anderem durch den Englisch-Unterricht an den Schulen und durch die Verfügbarkeit englischsprachiger Unterhaltungsmusik in den 60er und 70er Jahren, die zunehmende Internationalisierung der Arbeitswelt in den nachfolgenden Jahrzehnten und dauert mit der noch leichteren Verfügbarkeit englischsprachiger Inhalte durch das Internet bis heute an und wird auch noch weiterhin andauern.

Comment: ... *Wer genau?* - Jedermann --- *Wie viele genau?* Zuerst einer, dann zwei, dann drei usw. Jetzt sind wir bei mehreren Millionen. --- *"Vor allem Germanisten im Rentenalter" - hast du dafür einen Beleg?* - Meine persönliche Beobachtung. Wobei die "Germanisten im Rentenalter" pars pro toto für alle Menschen stehen, die sich noch daran erinnern können wie es früher war (im Sinn von *"früher war alles besser"*) und aufgrund dieser Erinnerung den Verfall der eigenen Muttersprache bedauern.

Answer (score 2):

Generell sind Warum-Fragen in der Linguistik schwer zu beantworten, da natürliche Sprachen nicht zweckvoll geplant werden, sondern das sich ständig verändende Resultat komplexer gesellschaftlicher Prozesse sind. Eine lückenlose Kausalkette wird in der Regel nicht zu finden sein.

Wir können jedoch nach Faktoren fragen, die möglicherweise den gegenwärtigen Status Quo beeinflusst haben.  Für diese Faktoren kommen unter anderem soziale, psycholgische und kognitionswissenschaftliche Faktoren in den Blick.

Ich möchte hier einen kognitionspsychologischen Aspekt beleuchten, der möglicherweise einen Einfluss gehabt hat. Ob dieser Aspekt tatsächlich ausschlaggebend dafür war, dass sich die Formulierung **etw. macht Unsinn* nicht etabliert hat, lässt sich aber nicht sagen. Es handelt sich also um eine "just-so-story". Allenfalls könnte sie als Arbeitshypothese für eine empirische oder experimentelle Studie fungieren. Mir ist aber nicht klar, wie sich eine solche Studie oder ein solches Experiment überhaupt durchführen ließe.

Die Formulierung *etw. macht Sinn* wird immer wieder als Anglizismus bezeichnet. Damit ließe sich die Debatte beenden. Die Antwort auf die Frage wäre dann: *etw. macht Sinn* ist ein Anglizismus, eine Übertragung des Englischen *sth. makes sense* und **etw. macht Unsinn* existiert deshalb nicht im Deutschen, weil auch im Englischen die entsprechende Formulierung **sth. makes nonsense* nicht existiert.

Aber erstens ist nicht sicher, ob es sich tatsächlich um einen Anglizismus handelt, und zweitens bliebe selbst dann unklar, wann und warum die Formulierung begonnen hat, in relevante Konkurrenz zu *etw. ergibt Sinn* oder *etw. ist sinnvoll* zu treten. Schließlich bliebe auch die Frage, warum die Formulierung **sth. makes nonsense* im Englischen nicht existiert.

In jedem Fall ist die Parallele zum Englischen bemerkenswert. Diese Parallele geht noch weiter: Sowohl im Deutschen als auch im Englischen lässt sich die Formulierung negieren: *st. does not make sense*, *etw. macht keinen Sinn*.

Die gestellte Frage lässt sich also auch so formulieren: Warum ist die Negierung *etw. macht keinen Sinn* akzeptiert, das vermeintlich gleichbedeutende **etw. macht Unsinn* aber nicht?

Eine Antwort könnte in folgendem  Unterschied der beiden Formulierungen liegen:

Der Verbindung *Sinn machen* liegt ein [konstrukivistischer](https://www.wikiwand.com/de/Konstruktivismus_(Philosophie)) Sinnbegriff zugrunde: "Sinn" ist nicht gegeben, sondern ist das Resultat eines Herstellungsprozesses.

Das ist nicht die einzige im Deutschen verbreitete Konzeptualisierung von *Sinn*. So gibt es auch eine Sinnvorstellung, in denen *Sinn* einer Sache selbst inhärent ist. Dieses Konzept wird etwa in der Formulierung *etw. ist sinnvoll* aufgerufen: hier wird *Sinn* nicht hergestellt, sondern lediglich festgestellt.

*Unsinn* heißt soviel wie "etw., das dumm, töricht ist". In diesem Sinne ist *Unsinn* kein konstruktivistischer Begriff. *Unsinn* ist nicht die Negation oder Abwesenheit eines herzustellenden Sinns, und wird auch selbst nicht hergestellt.

Die Formulierung *etw. macht Unsinn* enthält also eine Spannung: *machen* ruft ein konstruktivistisches Konzept auf, dem *Unsinn* aber nicht entspricht. Das könnte ein Grund sein, warum sich diese Formulierung weder im Englischen noch im Deutschen etabliert hat.

Im Gegensatz dazu verstößt die Negierung von *etw. macht Sinn* nicht gegen das konstruktivische Sinnkonzept, das durch das Verb *machen* aufgerufen wird: die negierte Aussage sagt dann eben gerade, dass eine Sache nicht dazu geeignet ist, Sinn herzustellen.

Als eine etwas vage Analogie zu dem Problem könnte man sich die Formulierung *Ein Loch mauern* denken, die ebenso gegen das Konzept des *Herstellens* verstößt: Man spricht nicht davon, ein Loch zu mauern, sondern allenfalls davon, eine Mauer zu mauern, die ein Loch hat. (In dieser Analogie nimmt *Sinn* die Rolle der Mauer ein, der *Unsinn* entspricht dem Loch und *machen* entspricht dem Mauern.)

Mit dieser Analyse harmoniert, dass auch der Formulierung *etw. ergibt Sinn* ein konstruktivistisches Sinnkonzept aufruft (genau wie *etw. macht Sinn*) und dass die Formulierung **etw. ergibt Unsinn* ebenfalls nicht existiert.

Comment: Deine letzten Absätze sind (sic) *Unsinn* (Verzeihung!) - Natürlich kann man ein Loch "machen". Wenn man ein Haus baut, *macht* man zuerst ein Loch in die Erde und baut den Keller hinein. *Unsinn* kann (z.B. für einen Komiker oder Clown) durchaus ein konstruktivistischer Begriff sein - Er verdient sogar seinen Lebensunterhalt damit, dass er *Unsinn macht*.

Comment: Sowohl "etw. macht Unsinn" als auch "etw. ergibt Unsinn" existieren durchaus.

Comment: @TilmanSchmidt Ah, interessant! Hast du vielleicht ein paar Belegstellen?

Comment: a) z.B. in diesem Blogpost https://www.kaffee-welt.net/index.php/Thread/7570-Jura-Impressa-E40-Trester-matschig-Kaffee-b%C3%A4h-Tresterbeh%C3%A4lter-wird-ausgeworfen/ "Die [Maschine] macht Unsinn." 
b) z.B. in https://www.gutefrage.net/frage/was-ist-bei-der-4-aufgabe-die-definitionsmenge "Teilen durch 0 ergibt Unsinn."

Comment: Mir kam schon der Gedanke, vorzuschlagen, dass mit "Warum" bzw. "Why" beginende Fragen automatisch ein -1 bekommen.

Comment: @TilmanSchmidt, aber bei *macht Unsinn* ist *machen* ganz klar als Synonym zu *treiben* aufzufassen. Das ist bei *macht Sinn* nicht der Fall, jedenfalls würde ich das niemals durch *treibt Sinn* ersetzen. Bei *ergibt Unsinn* sehe ich durchaus die Parallele zu *ergibt Sinn*.

Comment: @RHa Ich habe über das Problem der Warum-Fragen auch schon mal nachgedacht: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1625/what-is-the-problem-with-why-questions-and-how-to-deal-with-them

Comment: @tofro Das ist, glaube ich ein Missverständnis. Ich habe nich gemeint, dass man nicht sagen könne "ein Loch machen", sondern "ein Loch mauern". Es ist, wie gesagt, eine etwas vage Analogie. Wenn du ein besseres Beispiel für etwas Negatives hast, dass man nicht konstruieren kann, dann wäre ich dafür dankbar.

Comment: Ich habe (natürlich) kein besseres Beispiel, weil ich im Gegensatz zu dir der Ansicht bin, dass man die *Abwesenheit von etwas* durchaus *herstellen* kann - Auch wenn das der "reinen Logik" widersprechen mag (nur folgt eben Sprache nicht der "reinen Logik").

Comment: @tofro Stimmst du mit mir darin überein, dass man _ein Loch mauern_ nicht sagen würde?

Comment: Gerne. Genauso, wie ich ein z.B. Vakuum auch nicht *mauern* würde. *herstellen* kann man es aber schon. *mauern* ist ein spezielles Herstellungsverfahren, dass sich hauptsächlich für Wände eignet - nicht für Löcher. Man würde eine Mauer ja auch nicht *schweißen*.

Comment: Das scheint mir genau der logische Fehler in deiner Argumentation zu sein: Du möchtest die Tatsache, dass ein bestimmtes Herstellungsverfahren (hier "mauern") für ein bestimmtes Ding (hier "Loch") nichts taugt, unzulässig zur Aussage verallgemeinern, dass sich das Ding nicht konstruktivistisch herstellen ließe. Es gibt allerdings massenhaft funktionierende Herstellungsverfahren für Löcher wie Bohren, Stemmen, Brechen, (und, worum's eigentlich geht: auch "Machen")...

Comment: Auch wenn's in der Frage gar nicht darum geht: Das Problem mit dem *Sinn* ist, dass der immer schon da ist, man muss ihn nur finden - man kann ihn nicht *machen*. *Sinn* (oder *Unsinn*) sind absolute Konzepte (nämlich alles, was vernünftig und logisch ist, oder das Gegenteil davon), keine Dinge, die man "machen" kann. (In ähnlicher Logik wie der Bildhauer, der "einfach alles weghaut, was keine Skulptur ist - die war schon vorher da" und damit keine Skulptur "macht").